# Mouse wheel over luncher icon

Tags: unity

Unity allows to switch between windows of open programs by moving mouse wheel over  launcher icon. After mouse wheel is moved old windows disappear and new one appear. I would like to change configuration to prevent disappearing of old program window so it should start behave more like Alt-Tab.

How could I configure it?